# Hamiltonian Mechanics without a Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, definition

Let's say I want to develop Hamiltonian mechanics from scratch without going through Lagrangian mechanics and Legendre transformations. How would I go about doing that? What I am struggling with is a definition of conjugate momentum. It is usually defined as a derivative of Lagrangian, and there does not seem to be a natural way of defining it in terms of trajectory. Is there an alternative definition that does not involve a Lagrangian?

Comment: I highly recommend that you watch this lecture starting here. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQIbcV6dQzw&t=42m40s&ab_channel=Stanford p and q are related, through Hamilton's equations, such that phase space fluid is incompressible and blobs of volume in phase space are conserved.

Comment: When you say "develop it from scratch," do you mean starting from Newtonian mechanics and then generalizing to a symplectic manifold?

Comment: @J.Murray Yes, from Newtonian to Hamiltonian directly, using "natural" concepts from Newtonian mechanics. Or maybe Newtonian -> Hamilton-Jacobi -> Hamiltonian but the link from Newtonian to Hamilton-Jacobi would have to be "natural" and not refer to Hamiltonian function.

Answer (score 3):

You can just define some Hamiltonian $H(\vec{q},\vec{p})$ and the equations of motion are Hamilton's equations

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d} q_i}{{\rm d} t} &=& \frac{\partial H}{\partial p^i} \\
\frac{{\rm d} p^i}{{\rm d} t} &=& - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}
\end{eqnarray}

If you integrate the equations you'll get $q_i(t)$.

You might ask how to write down a Hamiltonian to represent a given system. If the system is fairly simple you can just start with a standard form like $H=\frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m} + V(\vec{q})$. For more complicated systems, it depends on the problem which formalism is the easiest to derive the equations of motion.

Finally I'll just mention that Hamiltonian mechanics is quite deep and there are some very beautiful geometric ways to formulate the theory as a symplectic manifold in a coordinate-independent way. If you have the mathematical background, this is an even more elegant way to formulate the equations; you just need to specify some two-form on the manifold that will generate the dynamics.

Comment: Sure, but you do that because you know what you will get (because you already know Lagrangian mechanics). This is not something a mathematician would do _naturally_. If you are presented with a differential equation $\ddot{x} = -\partial V(x)/\partial x$ it is natural to want to rewrite it as a set of two first-order equations $x' = ...$ and $\dot{x}' = ...$. What would prompt you to think: let me look for function H of two variables where the first variable is x and the second variable is some p such that $\dot{x} = \partial H/\partial p$ and $\dot{p} = - \partial H/\partial x$?

Comment: @Dzuku You don't need Lagrangian mechanics. As you said, you can formulate a 2nd order differential equation as 2 1st order ones, that is half way there."The real power of Hamiltonian mechanics comes from viewing it as a symplectic geometry and the dynamics preserve a phase space measure. Mathematically it isn't crazy to think about this kind of geometry. Physics-wise, I don't think anyone would have immediately jumped to the idea "dynamics can be described as a symplectic manifold", but the picture that built up over decades of work and proved its worth through the results you can prove.

Comment: I'm not an expert in the history of science, but a plausible physics reason you could look at Hamiltonian mechanics is by combining the ideas of "2nd order differential equation = 2 first order equations" and the fact that there is a special function (the energy), where the fact the dynamics come from the energy being constant.

Comment: Can I do this (recast in a symplectic form) for any 2nd order (even-order) differential equation? Or does my differential equation have to be special in some way?

Comment: It has to be special. The most straightforward way to say how it has to be special, is that it has to be derivable from a Lagrangian. But it's not the only way. If you start from the symplectic manifold picture, not every differential equation can be generated from an arbitrary two form.

Comment: Thank you. I think this almost answers my question. I will try to figure out the details myself. Do you know any textbook/book/resource that would explain this from a purely mathematical perspective? E.g. which ODEs can be recast in this way, etc? People like to refer to Arnold but I don't think he explains any of this.

Comment: @Dzuku Heh. I think it depends on exactly what your question is. If you want to know if a given arbitrary differential equation *can* be derived from a Lagrangian or Hamiltonian, I think this is a very hard problem. If you want to see what classes of differential equations you can get from a Lagrangian or Hamiltonian formalism, this is more tractable but I don't know of any source that does this systematically (I'm definitely more a physicist than a mathematician). If you don't like Arnold, Landau and Lifschitz is another great resource that is very sophisticated.

Comment: Thanks. I will reread Arnold and LL. Maybe it is there and I just don't remember. Basically, my question is. Given a second order ODE, how can I know whether it admits an equivalent description as a Symplectic flow?

Comment: @Dzuku I think that ("given a 2nd order ODE, how do I know if it can be derived from a Hamiltonian or Lagrangian") is a really a good question, and possibly worth asking either here on on math stack exchange to see if you get answers from someone with more knowledge. As far as I understand (but I wouldn't bet large sums of money on this), there isn't a general algorithm to tell you if an arbitrary equation can or can't be derived from a Hamiltonian/Lagrangian. But obviously there are specific examples that can be derived from one, and others that are known not to be derivable (eg friction).

Answer (score 0):

You *can* simply start with a Hamiltonian, but the Hamiltonian has to be written in terms of the correct Hamiltonian variables—the canonical coordinates and their conjugate momenta.  In one dimensions, that means that you can just write out a function $H=H(x,p)$ and derive Hamilton's equations from it in the usual way (e.g. $\dot{p}=\partial H/\partial x$).  The relation between the momentum $p$ and the velocity $\dot{x}$ (what you would get in the Lagrangian formalism by defining $p=\partial L/\partial\dot{x}$) is given by one of the Hamilton's equations instead, $\dot{x}=-\partial H/\partial p$. The generalization to multiple degrees of freedom is straightforward.

Comment: Sure, but you do that because you know what you will get (because you already know Lagrangian mechanics). This is not something a mathematician would do _naturally_. If you are presented with a differential equation $\ddot{x} = -\partial V(x)/\partial x$ it is natural to want to rewrite it as a set of two first-order equations $x' = ...$ and $\dot{x}' = ...$. What would prompt you to think: let me look for function H of two variables where the first variable is x and the second variable is some p such that $\dot{x} = \partial H/\partial p$ and $\dot{p} = - \partial H/\partial x$?

Comment: H is the energy. Or in field therory, the energy density. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_field_theory

Answer (score 0):

H is that thing which is invariant or conserved over time. This follows from Noether's Theorem. That thing is usually called energy.(It is also the generator of time translation. There is a connection between time translation and energy by Noether's Theorem.)

But there is a possibly even deeper explanation. This can be found in Leonard Susskind's Theoretical Minimum Vol 1 Lectures 8 and 9 and [his corresponding Classical Mechanics lectures on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQIbcV6dQzw&ab_channel=Stanford).

Hamilton's equations determine trajectories in phase space such that the volume of blobs in phase space are invariant. This can be shown by applying the mathematics of fluid flow to phase space. This is Louiville's Theorem.

If $F=F(p,q)$

In Classical Mechanics,

$\dot{F}=${$F,H$}.

-*Susskind Theoretical Minimum Vol 1. page 172.*

In Quantum Mechanics,

$\dot{L}=-\frac{i}{\hbar}$[L, H]

where $L$ is an operator.

-*Susskind Theoretical Minimum Volume 2.page 112.*

If you know the $H$ then you can easily calculate the equations of motion.

Consider two coupled oscillators.

$H =\frac{{p_1}^2}{2m_1}+\frac{{p_1}^2}{2m_1}+\frac{1}{2}k_1 {x_{1}^2}+\frac{1}{2}k_2 {x_{2}^2}+\frac{1}{2}k(x_2 − x_1)$.

-[Coupled Classical and Quantum Oscillators. McDermott. Redmount](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403184)

In quantum mechanics, $p$,$q$ and $H$ can be expressed in terms of raising a lowering operators. Then $H$ is an operator that acts on states. So, there are coupled *quantum* harmonic oscillators too.

-[Coupled Harmonic Oscillators. Applications of Quantum Mechanics. Cornell University.](http://quantum.lassp.cornell.edu/lecture/coupled_harmonic_oscillators)

The harmonic oscillator and $H=\frac{1}{2} p^2 + \frac{1}{2}\omega^2 q^2$ are fundamental to Quantum Field Theory.

[-Tong, David. Quantum Field Theory Lectures. page 22.](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html)

Comment: Hi Expert Nonexpert. Please see the [policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400) for linking to external resources e.g. on arXiv.